# django with gunicron and nginx

Tags: django, deployment, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I have developed django application and now deploying this on freebsd server using gunicron and nginx.  I have added guncorn in projects settings files under installedapps. and placed gunicorn.conf.py in root as:

```
import os

def numCPUs():
    if not hasattr(os, "sysconf"):
        raise RuntimeError("No sysconf detected.")
    return os.sysconf("SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN")

user = root
workers = numCPUs() * 2 + 1
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
pidfile = "/tmp/gunicorn-srv.pid"
backlog = 2048
logfile = "/data/logs/gunicorn_srv.log"
loglevel = "info"
```

Then in nginx.conf updated server tag with:

```
    listen       80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log;
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        #root   /usr/local/www/nginx;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location  /media/ {
        root /data/webs/uni_rate;
    }
    location  /static/ {
        root /data/webs/uni_rate;
    }
```

Now I have started nginx and guncorn. If I brows my public ip page is shown but static files are not served. If I directly hit

```
http://myip/static/folder/file.css
```

then 403 error is returned. Any Idea what could be the reason or what else information should be provided to diagnose it.

My media and static directories are respectively:

```
/data/webs/uni_rate/media
/data/webs/uni_rate/static
```

here is an output of nginx-access.log

```
182.178.6.248 - - [01/Apr/2013:11:14:54 -0500] "GET /static/bootstrap_toolkit_extras/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 403 168 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv
:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"
182.178.6.248 - - [01/Apr/2013:11:15:00 -0500] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Comment: You have `/media` and `/static` pointing to the same directory `/data/webs/uni_rate`. Firstly, is that actually the path for media or static and secondly, and if so, why are they the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the read permission of all of the parent folders of /data/webs/uni_rate/? Nginx user has to have read access to all of them. For example, /data, /data/webs, /data/webs/uni_rate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your *location* for *static* and *media* with something like this:

```
location /static {
    alias /var/www/domain1/media/;
    autoindex on;
    access_log off;
}
```

The trick is in 'alias' instead of 'root'.

Comment: what does it exactly do? Is autoindex safe? upvoted but @Chuan Ma: answer solved my issue So accepted.

Comment: autoindex is not necessary, I am using it now for development process, but anyway, just list the static directory, so I don't think it would not be safe.